# Google Analytics tracking conversion & cross domain

Tags: google-analytics

We have 4 websites which send traffic to an e-commerce.

Which is the best approach to optimize conversions?
I'd like to understand the pattern people follow to buy products also.

This is how I set up Google Analytics:
- cross domain tracking on all websites
- goal when people reach the order confirmation page

Thanks for any hints!
Andrea

Answer (score 1):

The question is too global as for me. There are numerous ways to optimize conversions. One of them is to see the e-commerce reports and analyze them. See which products or services are the most popular, improve them.

Then see the most unpoplular and improve them too.

To get more info and knowledges you should read books about GA and e-commerce. Also you may use GA help.